# Unable to get multi selected eav attribute values in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, eav, multiselect-attribute

I have a multi select attribute in **`eav_attribute`** with attribute_code **my_managers**, its **`entity_type_code`** is **customer_address**, I want to get selected value,,I am trying to export it to csv,in my protected `function _prepareColumns() {.....}` I am doing this. If single value is selected, it is working fine, but if multiple value are selected, then it shows an empty column.Multi select case is not working properly, other two cases are fine.I am doing this.

```
class Abc_AddressManager_Block_Adminhtml_Stores_Csv extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setIsExport(true);
    $this->setId('customer_address_grid');
    $this->setUseAjax(false);
    $this->setDefaultSort('store_id');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}


 protected function _prepareCollection() {
        $customer_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/address_collection');
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $select = $collection->getSelect();

    $select->joinLeft(
            array('customer' => $collection->getTable('customer/entity')), 'customer.entity_id=e.parent_id', array('email' => 'email')
    );

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns() {

    $addressModel = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
    $addressForm = Mage::getModel('customer/form');
    $addressForm->setFormCode('adminhtml_customer_address')
            ->setEntity($addressModel)
            ->initDefaultValues();
    $attributes = $addressForm->getAttributes();

    $this->addColumn('email', array(
        'header' => 'email',
        'type' => 'text',
        'index' => 'email',
        'filter' => false,
        'sortable' => false,
    ));

    $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
        'header' => 'address_id',
        'type' => 'text',
        'index' => 'entity_id',
        'filter' => false,
        'sortable' => false,
    ));

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        $code = $attribute->getData('attribute_code');
        if ($code == "additional_managers") {
            $x = 0;
        }
        switch ($attribute->getFrontendInput()) {
            case 'select' :
                $selectValues = array();
                $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
                foreach ($options as $option) {
                    $selectValues[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
                }
                $this->addColumn($code, array(
                    'header' => $code,
                    'type' => 'options',
                    'index' => $code,
                    'filter' => false,
                    'sortable' => false,
                    'options' => $selectValues
                ));

                break;
            case 'multiselect' :

                $selectValues = array();
                $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
                foreach ($options as $option) {
                    $selectValues[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
                }

                $this->addColumn($attribute->getAttributeCode(), array(
                    'header' => $attribute->getFrontendLabel(),
                    'type' => 'options',
                    'index' => $code,
                    'options' => $selectValues,
                    'renderer' => 'Abc_AddressManager_Block_Adminhtml_Stores_Render_Store',
                ));



                break;

            default :
                $this->addColumn($code, array(
                    'header' => $code,
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'index' => $code,
                    'filter' => false,
                    'sortable' => false
                ));
                break;
        }
    } // end

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

}

And my render is

```
 class Abc_sgAddressManager_Block_Adminhtml_Stores_Render_Store extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row){

        $id = $row->getEntityId();//Here row is csutomer address entity objetct,
        //Code will go here
    }
}
```

and one thing more, in db,comma separated values (values of selected options) is saved as shown in pic.
[image]
There one more catch, if I remove case of **"multiselect"**,just values of are shown for multi selected in csv.If selection is multiple, multiple values are show, With current code, it skips multiple selected options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->addColumn($code, array(
                'header' => $attribute->getFrontendLabel(),
                'type' => 'options',
                'index' => $code,
                'options' => $selectValues,
                'renderer'  => 'Namespace_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Code',
            ));
```

render block

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Code extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{

    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {


         $status=$row->getCode();
         //you code here 


         return $value;
    }

}
```

Comment: I am a little bit confused, in ** function render**, which code should I place,I am exporting it to csv, not to grid view

Comment: i know but first it is creating the gird am i right?

Comment: Yes, my class looks like this **class Namespace_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Stores_Csv extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid {...}**

Comment: for renderer use this for `extend Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract`

Comment: In render, if I do **$row->getEntityId()**, I am getting **entity id** of **customer_address_entity**, how should I relate it to get values from **customer_address_entity_varchar**, because I don't have attribute_id

Comment: you can get values directly from this `getCode`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35966/discussion-between-abdul-ghaffar-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: Hello Abdul,

Did you find any solution? why in export, multiselect attribute's column remains empty if multiple values are selected in it. I have the same issue & looking for the solution.

Thanks.