# Exporting Multiselect Attribute not working properly in magento

Tags: export, multiselect-attribute

I am facing one issue that is....I have one product in which I have one multi select attribute & I have selected 2 values in that. Now when I am exporting that product from System -> Import/Export -> Export then that column remains empty. If I select only 1 value & then export that product, then that one value comes in export. Why it is happening? What should I do to get all the selected values?

I referred one article but could not found the solution. That article is this
[Unable to get multi selected eav attribute values in magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102466/unable-to-get-multi-selected-eav-attribute-values-in-magento)

Thank You.

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Comment: Any suggestion please?